# Number Recognition on 7 segment using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am writing a code on Jupyter notebook using python to recognize the number on the device with 7segment(FND).

I used `opencv` and got the edge of the image.

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def detect_edge(image):
    ''' function Detecting Edges '''

    image_with_edges = cv2.Canny(image , 100, 200)

    images = [image , image_with_edges]

    location = [121, 122]

    for loc, img in zip(location, images):
        plt.subplot(loc)
        plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')

    plt.savefig('edge.png')
    plt.show()

image = cv2.imread('/Users/USER/Desktop/test/test2.png', 0)
detect_edge(image)
```

This is the screenshot of the sample input and output data I got form the code above:

[image: sample input and output]

I am not sure how to proceed from here. I want to get the recognize the number
51.12 in this case.

Should I crop the FND part that the numbers are on first before I run deep learning?

And how should I proceed from here?

Comment: *"this is the screenshot of the sample input and ouput data I got form the code above"* I only see the input, no output there! can you please check the link.

Comment: With such a limited number of possible digits on display and so little variation possible in the *"font"*, I would expect **OpenCV** *"Template Matching"* to work very well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I feel like using a CNN is overkill for a problem like this. Especially given that this is a 7-segment display we should be able to solve this without resorting to that kind of complexity.

You've marked out the corners so I'll assume that you can reliably crop out and un-rotate (make it flat) the display.

We want to grab just the numbers. In this case I first converted to LAB and thresholded on the b-channel.
[image]

Then I used opencv's findContours to mark out the perimeters:
[image]

After that I cropped out each individual number:

[image]

and then I looked for each segment individually and determined the number based on which segments were active (I used a special case for 1 where I checked the ratio of the width and height).

[image]

Here's the code I used (two files)
segments.py

```py
import numpy as np

class Segments:
    def __init__(self):
        # create a 7seg model
        self.flags = [];
        self.segments = [];
        h1 = [[0, 1.0],[0, 0.1]];       # 0
        h2 = [[0, 1.0],[0.45, 0.55]];   # 1
        h3 = [[0, 1.0],[0.9, 1.0]];     # 2
        vl1 = [[0, 0.2],[0, 0.5]];      # 3 # upper-left
        vl2 = [[0, 0.2],[0.5, 1.0]];    # 4
        vr1 = [[0.8, 1.0],[0, 0.5]];    # 5 # upper-right
        vr2 = [[0.8, 1.0], [0.5, 1.0]]; # 6
        self.segments.append(h1);
        self.segments.append(h2);
        self.segments.append(h3);
        self.segments.append(vl1);
        self.segments.append(vl2);
        self.segments.append(vr1);
        self.segments.append(vr2);

    # process an image and set flags
    def digest(self, number):
        # reset flags
        self.flags = [];

        # check res to see if it's a one
        h, w = number.shape[:2];
        if w < 0.5 * h:
            self.flags.append(5);
            self.flags.append(6);
            return;

        # check for segments
        for a in range(len(self.segments)):
            seg = self.segments[a];
            # get bounds
            xl, xh = seg[0];
            yl, yh = seg[1];
            # convert to pix coords
            xl = int(xl * w);
            xh = int(xh * w);
            yl = int(yl * h);
            yh = int(yh * h);
            sw = xh - xl;
            sh = yh - yl;
            # check
            count = np.count_nonzero(number[yl:yh, xl:xh] == 255);
            if count / (sh * sw) > 0.5: # 0.5 is a sensitivity measure
                self.flags.append(a);

    # returns the stored number (stored in self.flags)
    def getNum(self):
        # hardcoding outputs
        if self.flags == [0,2,3,4,5,6]:
            return 0;
        if self.flags == [5,6]:
            return 1;
        if self.flags == [0,1,2,4,5]:
            return 2;
        if self.flags == [0,1,2,5,6]:
            return 3;
        if self.flags == [1,3,5,6]:
            return 4;
        if self.flags == [0,1,2,3,6]:
            return 5;
        if self.flags == [0,1,2,3,4,6]:
            return 6;
        if self.flags == [0,5,6]:
            return 7;
        if self.flags == [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]:
            return 8;
        if self.flags == [0,1,2,3,5,6]:
            return 9;
        # ERROR
        return -1;
```

main.py

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from segments import Segments

# load image
img = cv2.imread("seg7.jpg");

# crop
img = img[300:800,100:800,:];

# lab
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB);
l,a,b = cv2.split(lab);

# show
cv2.imshow("orig", img);

# closing operation
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8);

# threshold params
low = 165;
high = 200;
iters = 3;

# make copy
copy = b.copy();

# threshold
thresh = cv2.inRange(copy, low, high);

# dilate
for a in range(iters):
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel);

# erode
for a in range(iters):
    thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel);

# show image
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh);
cv2.imwrite("threshold.jpg", thresh);

# start processing
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

# draw
for contour in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], 0, (0,255,0), 3);

# get res of each number
bounds = [];
h, w = img.shape[:2];
for contour in contours:
    left = w;
    right = 0;
    top = h;
    bottom = 0;
    for point in contour:
        point = point[0];
        x, y = point;
        if x < left:
            left = x;
        if x > right:
            right = x;
        if y < top:
            top = y;
        if y > bottom:
            bottom = y;
    tl = [left, top];
    br = [right, bottom];
    bounds.append([tl, br]);

# crop out each number
cuts = [];
number = 0;
for bound in bounds:
    tl, br = bound;
    cut_img = thresh[tl[1]:br[1], tl[0]:br[0]];
    cuts.append(cut_img);
    number += 1;
    cv2.imshow(str(number), cut_img);

# font 
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;

# create a segment model
model = Segments();
index = 0;
for cut in cuts:
    # save image
    cv2.imwrite(str(index) + "_" + str(number) + ".jpg", cut);

    # process
    model.digest(cut);
    number = model.getNum();
    print(number);
    cv2.imshow(str(index), cut);

    # draw and save again
    h, w = cut.shape[:2];
    drawn = np.zeros((h, w, 3), np.uint8);
    drawn[:, :, 0] = cut;
    drawn = cv2.putText(drawn, str(number), (10,30), font, 1, (0,0,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA);
    cv2.imwrite("drawn" + str(index) + "_" + str(number) + ".jpg", drawn);
    
    index += 1;
    # cv2.waitKey(0);


# show
cv2.imshow("contours", img);
cv2.imwrite("contours.jpg", img);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

I can't guarantee that this always works, but it should be usable given a little tweaking. Remember to un-rotate the image if it isn't flat. The segment model assumes the numbers are mostly upright.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! The output seems really neat. I have a question. I am using a Jupyter notebook and when I try to run your code on it, the  'from segments import Segments'part  have an import error.                                                           --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------cannot import name 'Segments' from 'segments' (C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\opencv\lib\site-packages\segments\__init__.py) --------- how should I trouble shoot this?   I tried pip install segments. Thanks a lot

Comment: And if you can tell me  which  development tool did you use, that would be awesome~

Comment: I used opencv and numpy. The segment.py file must be in the same folder, or at least reachable from wherever main.py is being run from. I'm not sure how Jupyter notebooks are organized, but basically make sure to include it however you would normally include additional files in a Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use deep learning, one way to approach this would be to use a convolutional neural network (CNN). Whether you first want to crop the images depends on your application. Do you want to recognize the display from a picture like the one you attached? Then you should not crop the image manually. Furthermore you would need a lot of data to train your own CNN.

An alternative would be to use an off-the-shelf Optical Character Recognition engine such as tesseract [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/). These are already trained and can achieve good results. I have no experience with detecting 7 segment displays though, so it could be that they do not work for 7 segment displays. They have tried OCR with tesseract for 7 segment displays here: [ocr + 7 segment display](https://github.com/upupnaway/digital-display-character-rec).

Last thing you could try is first detect the display from a large picture and then feed the cropped region that was detected to an OCR engine.

Answer (score 0):

dot point Issue ~ the dot Point on right bottom of each Numbers seem to impact especially the recognition rate of right botton side variable vr2 #6 checking while checking Numpy.NonZero(in your sample code) when dot point was light on (while image threshed & findcontours)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).